# Existence of open disc iff existence of open rectangle

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove: A set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a union of open discs if and only if it is a union open rectangles.

First off, I know that I am not supposed to directly ask for a proof but I have thought about this for a long time and I have looked at other proofs similar to such wording, but I have not found any references. I am not asking for a direct proof, but one that just helps me get started and what I should do with it, of course if one provides me with a step by step solution I would also be grateful for whatever help you deem is fit for me to learn this! thank you!

I am given these definitions:

Open disc with centre $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and radius $r>0$: $\{ (x,y)\mid (x-a)^2 +(y-b)^2< r^2 \}$.

Open Rectangle $(a,b) \times (c,d)$, where $a< b, c < d$ in $\Bbb R$: $\{ (x,y)\mid a < x < b, c< y < d\}$.

P.S. pardon my English as my first language is Dutch

Answer (score 1):

Can you show that within an open disc and given a point inside that you can fit an open rectangle around that point inside that disc? 
Conversely given a point inside an open rectangle can you fit an open disc around that point such that the disc is contained inside the rectangle?

Comment: do you mean i should just sub the equation of circle into rectangle and vice versa?

Comment: I didn’t get your point but can you see my claim geometrically ?

Comment: yes I can, my point is do I solve for x in the circle equation and put this equation into the equation of rectangles to show that it works?

Comment: Actually you need to modify the radius there. You see you can even insert a open disc based at the chosen point inside the given disc also. So if you can prove for $0\in B(0, r) $ that there is a rectangle containing 0 in the open disc $B(0, r) $ and similarly the other case you will be done.

Comment: but what is the B you are referring to here?

Comment: B stands for ball in metric space notations

Comment: you said insert a open disc based at the chosen point inside the given disc, would you elaborating on this? DOes that mean you can insert a disc in a disc?

Comment: Yes. Suppose the point is P and you have a disc D of radius r around this you can insert a rectangle R in D such that $P\in R \subset D$ you can interchange D and R with suitable change in the diameters (this is a common term for rectangle as well as disc)  you can insert a smaller disc centering at P in D also

Comment: could you elaborate why you used 0∈(0,), I understand that this is the metric space, however why did you use the set 0?

Comment: If you can do it for 0 translating to other center points it is done for every point.

Comment: when you use 0 here, is that the circle or the rectangle , i am really tripping up on all the notation..

Comment: You can do it either way

Comment: could you show the first three lines of the prove explicitly?

Comment: Let $p\in B(p, r) := { (x, y) : (x-a)^2+(y-b) ^2<r^2}$ then for $p=(a, b) $ $ (a-r/2, a+r/2) \times (b-r/2, b+r/2) \subset B(p, r) $.